# "Tratado" vs. "trato"

Tags: vocabulario

Dictionaries say both mean treaty or treatment except that **tratado** also happens to be the past participle of **tratar**. Other than **tratado**'s meaning as the past participle of **tratar**, that's the difference between them?

To add to the confusion, **trato** also means treatment. But then so does **tratamiento**! How are **trato** and **tratamiento** different in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start with `tratado` can have other meanings beyond the past participle of *tratar*. It can be:

1- An **official** agreement (treaty, like the [Treaty of Tordesillas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas) o Tratado de Tordesillas)

> El **tratado** de XXX le daba la mitad del imperio a un rey y la otra mitad a otro.

And **official** is the keyword there. It is the kind of agreement that you get when the parties involved might be kingdoms, empires, the pope, etc.

2- A book, discussion or work about a certain matter, generally long, extensive and deep (treatise)

> El Libro de YYY es el mejor **tratado** sobre matemáticas escrito en el siglo XIII

`Trato`, apart of the variations for `Tratar` can mean also an agreement, but is more like a comercial or mundane agreement than the official agreement of `Tratado`.

> Tengo un **trato** con mi socio. Él se encarga de las finanzas y yo del papeleo burocrático.

You could even have an *informal* trato with somebody

> Tengo un **trato** con mi padre. Si saco todo sobresalientes me dejará usar su coche los fines de semana.
>
> Te propongo un **trato**, si tú barres el suelo yo friego los platos y hagos las camas.

Note that in Spanish we would favor **acuerdo** for a legal agreement (for example between two companies) instead of **trato**.

About the difference between `trato` and `tratamiento`, when referring about addressing to somebody, I think there is no big difference. Maybe just personal preferences to pick one word or the other.

> A: Deberías corregir la cabecera de ese email, el **tratamiento** correcto para esa persona es debería ser "*de usted*" y no "*de tú*".
>
> B: En serio? Yo siempre le trato "*de tú*" cuando le veo!.

That `treatment` could also mean *medical treatment*, in which case is always `tratamiento` and never `trato`.

> El **tratamiento** para esta enfermedad consiste simplemente en una vacuna.